# Checking elements of a list Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
places=["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]
place = places[0]
while places != "Sochi" and count < len(places):

    if ' ' in place:
        multi_word += 1

    count += 1
    place = places[count]
```

I basically want the program to check how many cities till Sochi, by adding one for each element of the list. Then when it reaches Sochi it stops adding 1 to the list  then it do nothing when it reaches Sochi. The program adds one for every element of the list. Then it checks if their is a space in any of the elements of the list and if so adds one but only if that element of the list comes from Sochi. What is wrong with this program? 
Also what does this line do..{count < len(places)}

Answer (score 1):

The main error I see is that you need to check `if place != "Sochi"`, instead of using `places`. Assuming you initialize `count=0`, this will give you the output you desire:

```
places = ["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]
place  = places[count]
while place != "Sochi" and count < len(places):

    if ' ' in place:
        multi_word += 1

    count += 1
    place = places[count]

print 'Number of cities before Sochi:', count
```

The clause `count < len(places)` makes sure that you don't try access indices in `places` beyond the length of the list, which would return an `IndexError`.

Answer (score -3):

```
places = ["Jack", "John", "Sochi"]
count=0
multi_word=0
place  = places[count]
while place != "Sochi" and count < len(places):
    if ' ' in place:
        multi_word += 1

    count += 1
    place = places[count]

print ('Number of cities before Sochi:', count)
```

Here is the fixed code